# Android - stop code midway?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, text-to-speech

I am using a the TextToSpeech service. This is what my code looks like:

```
Speak("Test1");
Speak("Test2");
Speak("Test3");
Speak("Test4");
Speak("Test5");
//
public void Speak(String t)
{
if(enabled)
tts.speak(t);
}
```

In between the the 5 messages (test1->test5), there is a possibility of the boolean 'enabled' to be changed to false. However, if the code is started and then the boolean is changed to false, all 5 messages go through. I assume this is because all 5 "Speaks" are 'sent' almost instantly, faster than the boolean being changed. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the field declaration of **enabled**. Did you declare it as static? I guess you may not have declared it as static and **enabled** will come inside the scope of the object and not on the class. Also if you are using multithreading, use volatile for **enabled**.

PS: This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on this question.

Comment: If I set enabled = false inbetween Speak("Test1") and Speak("Test2"), only Test1 will be spoken. If I set enabled=false somewhere else (i.e. from a button) while the code is ran, it will speak all 5 things. I'm assuming this is because I don't press the button fast enough for all 5 Speaks to be 'added', which I'm going to assume is mere milliseconds.

Comment: I may need the full code for me to help you. I can understand your problem but I need to see your code for finding out where you are missing the track.  In my assumption, you have already called all 5 speak calls and the button click gets queued up after the 5 speak calls.

Comment: The only thing that is missing from the code is a button that sets enabled to false. Basically, one button executes the 5 Speaks. Another button sets enabled = false. I tap button one, then tap button two.

Comment: Unless you post the code its difficult to help you. Use the following code Snippet to address the issue.

`public class Speak {


  private static boolean isEnabled;

  public void speak(String t) {

     if(isEnabled) {

      ...//code to speak the text

    } 
  }
}`

Comment: What you are noticing is exactly how the system will behave almost all the time. By the time you click the second button, all the speak function would have already been called. You can confirm this by printing log messages before each speak is called and print the value of enabled. Remember there is only one UI thread that is processing all your actions. If you really want to simulate second button interrupting the first button action, you may want to use another thread for starting speak(s). Or may be you want to rethink your strategy itself (do you need to call all speaks to start with?)